# How to handle ErrorEventhandler with a thread to update a SQL table?

Tags: vb.net

I have an application which runs two threads.

- One thread is the main thread while the other one is to monitor the main thread.
- The errors are written to a custom event log
- There is an event handler to handle the event logs
- When an event occurs I want to create a new thread
  and update the event to a sql table (pseudo code)
- Also in case their are number of errors/events
  how should I handle them (pseudo code)

I would appreciate if any one can help with some sort of pseudo code for the above two items.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your error event handler...

```
Dim thdLogError as New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf MethodThatLogsError(ErrorObjectThatGetsPassedIn))
thdLogError.Start()
```

Then you can insert the error to the database in your MethodThatLogsError procedure.
I imagine you get one error at a time, but if you are getting multiple you will have to iterate through the array or list of errors you are getting.